# Add a class on div to change a default css

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, addition, using

```
  var totalForDay = parseFloat(twodecimalDomforDay) + parseFloat(twodecimalImportforDay);
             totalForDay = totalForDay.toFixed(2);
             var totalyearly = parseFloat(twodecimalDomforYearly) + parseFloat(twodecimalImportyearly);
             totalyearly = totalyearly.toFixed(2);
             badgesData += '<div class="row For-Avg"><div class="col-xs-6 sm-6 md-6 lg-6 left-align"><label class="for-lab">For The Day</label></div><div class="col-xs-6 sm-6 md-6 lg-6 right-align"><label class="year-lab">Yearly Avg</label></div></div><div class="row For-Avg"><div class="col-xs-6 sm-6 md-6 lg-6 left-align"><label class="for-lab-Two">' + totalForDay + '</label></br><div class="border-cls"></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 sm-6 md-6 lg-6 right-align"><label class="year-lab-Two">' + totalyearly + '</label></br><div class="border-cls-Two"></div></div></div></div>';
             gasTitle += '<label class="lab-class">' + objKeys[i] + '\n(IN &nbsp' + objkeysData[0].UNIT + ')' + '</label>';
             if (parseFloat(totalForDay) < parseFloat(totalyearly)) {
                 console.info("less yes");
                 $("div.border-cls").css("border-bottom", "7px solid red");
                 $("div.border-cls-Two").css("border-bottom", "7px solid green");
                 //-----border-red for day border-green for yealy
             } else {
                 //-----border-green for day border-red for yealy
                 console.info("greatre yes");
                 $("div.border-cls").css("border-bottom", "7px solid green");
                 $("div.border-cls-Two").css("border-bottom", "7px solid red");
             }
```

Hello Team,

In given Html named as badgesData, It contains a div with added class named as border-cls. I want that after execution of condition which is mentioned in source code as if(totalForday

KIndly suggest me and help me for the same.

Comment: Its unclear to me what you're asking really.

Comment: 1).In badgesData+=//----mentioned a div with class name as border-cls I have defined this css in my app.css style file.  As well I checked one of my condition after gastitle. As if(parseFloat(totalForDay)<parseFloa(totalyearly)){In this place I want to change my Border-cls class property. } How can I do it.

Comment: ..and what the problem is?

Comment: If I print a console after check my less or greater condition, It is giving me correct result but css is not effecting on div with classs as border-cls.

Comment: Are you using !important rule anywhere?

Comment: No I am not using !important...Please suggest me How can I resolve this one. $("div.border-cls").css("border-bottom", "7px solid red");
                 $("div.border-cls-Two").css("border-bottom", "7px solid green"); If I am using this one.

Comment: I see no problem in your code.

Comment: Try defining the width for the border div.

Comment: No Effect If I define a width for my div with class as border-cls.After satisfying with condition no css executing. Any Other Idea to implement the same functionality.

Comment: Try defining styles in your stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be missing {} inside the method css()
Please try the below code

```
 if (parseFloat(totalForDay) < parseFloat(totalyearly)) {
             console.info("less yes");
             $("div.border-cls").css({"border-bottom": "7px solid red"});
             $("div.border-cls-Two").css({"border-bottom" :"7px solid green"});
             //-----border-red for day border-green for yealy
         } else {
             //-----border-green for day border-red for yealy
             console.info("greatre yes");
             $("div.border-cls").css({"border-bottom": "7px solid green"});
             $("div.border-cls-Two").css({"border-bottom": "7px solid red"});
         }
```